# How to define a polymorphic reference variable in scala

Tags: scala

I have just started to explore Scala. suppose I have the following code:

```
abstract class Shape
case class Square() extends Shape
case class Circle() extends Shape
case class Triangle() extends Shape
```

Having that, I can define a reference referring to Shape in java, and then I can store objects of Shape subclasses in it as bellow:

```
Shape s=null;
s=new Circle(); 
s=new Square();
s=new Triangle();
```

**my Question:**
what is the above code counterpart in scala (note that I do want to define only one variable, namely s here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
var s: Shape = null
s = Circle()
s = Square()
s = Triangle()
```

If you're an `Option`-zealot:

```
var s: Option[Shape] = None
s = Some(Circle())
s = Some(Square())
s = Some(Triangle())
```

If you're a [`val`-zealot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc4pY.png):

```
val s1 = Circle()
val s2 = Square()
val s3 = Triangle()
```

Contrary to popular belief, `var` and `null` are totally fine in small scopes.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a code like this:

```
var s: Shape = null
s = new Circle()
s = new Square()
s = new Triangle()
```

However, Scala is originally meant to be used functionally. So you should use `val` instead of `var` as much as possible. `val` is very similar to `final` in Java.

Every time you use `var` instead of `val` you should be 100% sure you want to do that.

Moreover, try to avoid `null`s at all. Instead, use `Option`. Maybe you're interested in some literature such as [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644)